# Unreachable field "isTeam0" in PHPUnit / Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a checkbox:

```
<input class="switch" data-on-text="Si" data-off-text="No" id="isTeam0" 
checked="checked" name="isTeam" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

When I try to make a functional test with:

```
$this->visit('/tournaments/' . $tournament->id . '/edit')
        ->type('1', 'isTeam0')
        ->press('save0');
```

I get this error message:

```
1) TournamentTest::it_create_tournament_category_conf
```

InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "isTeam0"

```
/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/FormFieldRegistry.php:89
/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/FormFieldRegistry.php:126
/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Form.php:77
/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:711
/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:691
/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:678
/home/vagrant/Code/tests/functional/TournamentTest.php:187
```

I don't know what to do to make it work...

Any Idea???